# Service block reduce delay time using resource pool workers

Tags: anylogic

I have a resource pool and a service block. The number of the operator in the resource pool is 5 which is linked to the service block. I would like to setup the service in a way that the more workers work on the service the delay time decreases. (ex: if 1 worker works the delay time is 10 min - if 2 workers work the delay time is 5 min. - if 3 workers work the delay time is 3.33 min). I would like up to 5 operators to be working at the same time in the service block based on their availability.
[Service Block and Resource Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJy1e.jpg)
How can I achieve this?

Comment: currently, you only ever seize 1 worker anyway, see your Service properties. Fix that first :)

Comment: Thanks to your reply. When you say fix service properties, Do you mean the number of units?

Comment: yes, check the help to understand the various properties, but your "number of units" is 1 so every agent will always only seize 1 resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to do two things with your Service block:

- Seize a dynamic number of units (in the simplest case, seize all available units).
- Have the delay time dependent on the number of units seized (in the simplest case, just decreasing multiplicatively according to the number of resources).

For the former, assuming you're seizing from a single pool, just enter a dynamic expression in the "Number of units" property. In the simplest case (seize all available) it would just be `pool.idle()` (for a resource pool called `pool`) but that's problematic if the next agent arrives whilst the first is being processed (because it will be treated as needing zero resources) so, depending what you want, you might need to do something like put  RestrictedAreaStart / End blocks around your Service block so only one agent can be in the Service block at once.

**NB**: AnyLogic currently has a bug/limitation that the resource pool's idle/busy counts (from its `idle()` and `busy()` functions) *are not guaranteed to be correct unless you are at a later simulation time than when seizes/releases occurred*. (This is due to how things are resolved in hidden events under-the-covers.) So, if you want to use them in your determination of the number of resources to seize you need to work round this; e.g., by

- tracking the number of busy/idle units via your own counts;
- using the `isIdle()` function on individual resources in the pool instead (which typically requires ensuring the resource pool agents are in a custom population, not the hidden default one, so you can explicitly reference/loop through them);
- something horrible and hacky like adding a very-small-timeout Delay block before entering a Service block (possibly within RestrictedAreaStart / Ends to ensure that agents don't make it into the Delay, and hence the Service block's seize mechanism, until you want them to).

In general, it makes sense to put the resources-needed calculation in a function (which returns an `int` and takes the agent as an argument) which you call in the "Number of units" expression. That way you can make the calculation as complex as you like; it would seem you might need a more complex consideration than just "grab everyone" (e.g., perhaps depending on the stream of to-arrive agents if you have knowledge of them, etc.). Maybe, for example, you'd also want to hold your arriving agents in a Wait block beforehand and only release them when the number of resources you want are available. (You'd need to give more precise detail about your requirements to be any more definite here.)

For the variable delay time, have an appropriate dynamic expression for the delay time; you can use the `resourceUnits()` function to get a list of the resource units seized by your agent. So, in the simplest case (decreases multiplicatively according to the number of resources) it would be something like `10.0 / agent.resourceUnits().size()` (for a base delay of 10 time units).